# NodeJS hosting on linux VM, and http requests from Windows to Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, react-native

If I'm hosting a local NodeJS server on an Ubuntu Linux Machine, is it possible to make http requests from a browser on Windows. For instance if the server is hosted on localhost:7700 on the Linux VM, how can I make http requests from Windows on?

The server is hosted with NodeJS on a Linux VM.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set port forwarding. If you are using Virtual Box look here [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/). Instead of localhost:7700 try using 0.0.0.0:7700. Also remember to open 7700 port on your machine. The last thing is to set your network as bridged adapter to allow connection between your host OS and VM.

Comment: How would I do that on hyperv?